# Country restriction while using google place API nearby search

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api, country, restrictions

I'm creating a web application to search business organisations in an area. User will provide keyword and zip code for the search.

For searching, Place API Nearbysearch functionality is used. Latitude, longitude, radius and keyword are given for the request. I give radius of 10000. But while searching for businesses with a zip code of California, I got a business from Mexico also. I can't reduce the value of radius.

How can I get places only in the country of the zip code provided by the user?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible to filter Place results by country. None of the parameters for the API include a filter by geographic name.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

What I would do is pull all results and filter results within your own code.  The downside (besides your app doing more work and using more bandwidth) is that as you only get 20 results per page, you may have to pull multiple pages to get the desired number of results.